# problems plotting special characters (slovene) to knitr latex reports

Tags: r, encoding, knitr

I'm having trouble printing special characters (ščž) to a pdf report made by knitr.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[slovene]{babel}

\begin{document}

<<>>=
plot(runif(100), main = "ŠČĆŽ ščćž")
@

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [comments by Yihui](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/172) (see also comments below), here's a solution that worked for me. The `.Rnw` document I'm working with is encoded as UTF-8.

The key is to specify encoding to `knit`.

[image]

Notice that we're still missing the "č" (for non-native speakers, you can read this character as "ch").

The issue can be resolved by specifying a different printing device. Consider specifying `dev = "CairoPDF"` (requires additional `CairoPDF` package) or `dev = "cairo_pdf"` (requires no additional packages) in your chunk option.

```
<<dev = "CairoPDF">>=
plot(runif(100), main = "ŠČĆŽ ščćž")
@
```

or

```
<<dev = "cairo_pdf">>=
plot(runif(100), main = "ŠČĆŽ ščćž")
@
```

[image]

If you're using Eclipse + StatET to weave your reports, you can set these options to automate the workflow.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, my comment that you mentioned about the encoding is no longer appropriate. Now you should use `knit(..., encoding='UTF-8')` if you know the document is UTF-8 encoded. It is much safer than `options(encoding = 'UTF-8')`. For the graphical device, you can also try `cairo_pdf`, which is shipped with base R, i.e. no add-on packages required.

Comment: @Yihui well, that... simplifies things. :) I'll edit my answer to reflect the newly found wisdom.